# TWILIO: ¿How to know the number of a forwarded caller?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there any way to know the number of a forwarded number with twilio?

Example: A calls B. B forwards the number to a twilio number. Is it possible to know the number of A?

Right now, I am only able to see the B number ( in the "from" and "caller" properties of the call.

Thanks in advance

Ander

Answer (score 0):

Not a consistent way. The [ForwardedFrom](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) Key is Carrier Dependent.